# Objective C syntax differences

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I came across this kind of syntax a while ago :

```
[myView setFrame:({
    CGRect frame = myView.frame;
    frame.size.height = heightValue;
    frame;
})];
```

I can't remember where I saw this, but I was wondering if there are any advantages in using it instead of the classic :

```
CGRect frame = myView.frame;
frame.size.height = heightValue;
[myView setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Somehow that construct looks less weird now that we have blocks floating around in our code. But still, if the `frame` variable really has to be protected that strongly from being overwritten by other parts of the same method, then maybe that code could do with a review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The former syntax simply constrains the scope of `frame` such that the temporary storage that was used to create it can be reclaimed after the `setFrame` message send.

In my opinion however, this is one of those things that adds mental effort in reading code for an optimization that a compiler will almost certainly take anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It prevents `frame` from being scoped outside of the call to `setFrame:`, but at the expense of readability.

Answer (score 1):

The first syntax is a GNU extension to C language, called [*Statement Expression*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). It is incompatible with any of C standards, so you would be better off avoiding altogether in favor of the second syntax, which is a lot more readable.